# How to delete all UUID from fstab but not the UUID of boot filesystem

Tags: text-processing, rhel, fstab

on the following example `fstab` file, we want to delete all lines that start with `UUID` , but except the `UUID` line with `boot` word

```
/dev/mapper/VG100-lv_root /                       xfs     defaults        0 0
UUID=735cb76a-51b5-4e06-b6fb-3b9577e38dc5 /boot                   xfs     defaults        0 0
/dev/mapper/VG100-lv_var /var                    xfs     defaults        0 0


UUID=0b14011d-f69d-4c4c-8ce0-6240bb0a574a   /var/kafka/mp1                      xfs defaults,noatime 0 0
UUID=2d7872f2-96d4-4ba9-8a17-a1115542645c   /var/kafka/mp2                      xfs defaults,noatime 0 0
UUID=79bdbf56-9a09-4505-ab8e-41ce9432cf0f   /var/kafka/mp3                      xfs defaults,noatime 0 0
UUID=ca42a388-83d4-4f8b-aff7-3450d836eef7   /var/kafka/mp4                      xfs defaults,noatime 0 0
UUID=62d356bb-c393-4a74-bbf9-984b60d3b5c4   /var/kafka/mp5                      xfs defaults,noatime 0 0
UUID=d4071a83-204f-475f-8917-cdd77ef6b1ed   /var/kafka/mp6                      xfs defaults,noatime 0 0
```

so excepted results should be as following

```
/dev/mapper/VG100-lv_root /                       xfs     defaults        0 0
UUID=735cb76a-51b5-4e06-b6fb-3b9577e38dc5 /boot                   xfs     defaults        0 0
/dev/mapper/VG100-lv_var /var                    xfs     defaults        0 0
```

so far we have the following sed

```
 sed -i '/^UUID/d'  /etc/fstab
```

but above approach deletes all `UUID` lines

Comment: I would have used kafka as keyword

Comment: Have you considered manually editing the file instead? This is one of those situations where a single typo could ruin your entire day trying to recover and it's not something you'll be doing all that often -- and if you *do* have dozens of machines may I recommend some degree of actual automation instead of shell scripting?

Comment: no because we need to do it on all machines in our domain, we have - 2765 machines.

Comment: Then by all that is holy and bright and kind, get some better automation tools than a `sed` script -- [ansible](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/posix/mount_module.html) has a module specifically for this kind of thing.

Comment: Are all your machines always guaranteed to have GNU sed? The currently accepted answer relies on the answer to that question being "yes".

Comment: This isn't the question you asked, but if all of your machines are similar what about focusing instead on deleting all of the lines with `/var/kafka/*` or only keeping the first 3 lines of the file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First tell sed to print lines which contain `boot`, then tell it to delete lines which contain `UUID`, separate expressions with `;`

```
sed -i '/boot/p;/UUID/d' /etc/fstab
```

Since the print expression was given before delete expression, line which contains boot will be printed, before the lines with UUID are deleted, if you would changes expression positions, this would not work.

Given the example you gave, you should get something like this

```
/dev/mapper/VG100-lv_root /                       xfs     defaults        0 0
UUID=735cb76a-51b5-4e06-b6fb-3b9577e38dc5 /boot                   xfs     defaults        0 0
/dev/mapper/VG100-lv_var /var                    xfs     defaults        0 0
```

You can also add the part to delete empty lines, `^` marks the start of line, and `$` marks the end of line, so add expression to delete lines that that have the end `$` of line right after beginning of the line `^`.

```
sed -i '/boot/p;/UUID/d;/^$/d' /etc/fstab
```

---

---

EDIT

As noted in the comments by Stéphane Chazelas this will print the line which contains boot twice, if it doesn't contain UUID in the same line, so something like this would be better.

```
sed -i '/^UUID/{/boot/!d};/^$/d' /etc/fstab
```

It will delete lines which start with UUID, except if they contain /boot, and then delete all empty lines

Comment: Might be a bit better to use `sed -i.bak 'm|/boot|p; /UUID/d; /^$/d' /etc/fstab` so that i) you have a backup of the original, just in case, and ii) it only matches `/boot` and not something like `bootcopy` or `reboot` anything else.

Comment: `sed '/boot/p;/UUID/d'` would print the lines that contain `/boot` and not `UUID` twice.

Comment: `sed '/boot/p;/UUID/d'` would print lines that contain `boot` twice and delete lines that contain `UUID` if either appeared in some other part of the line than where you want to match them, including as substrings, e.g. `/dev/mapper/UUID100-lv_root` or `/var/kafka/reboot1`.

Comment: your second suggestion -0 sed -i '/^UUID/{/boot/!d};/^$/d' /etc/fstab , will delete the UUID lines only if they started in the beginning, its ok , but sometimes when some person decided to give a space before the UUID VIA vi then its different case.  so on that case it will not remove the UUID

Answer (score 6):

Seems to me  you want to delete lines whose first field starts with `UUID=` and second field is not `/boot`.

So `awk` or perl's awk mode would seem an obvious choice:

```
awk '! ($1 ~ /^UUID=/ && $2 != "/boot")' /etc/fstab
```

(GNU awk can edit in place with `-i /usr/share/awk/inplace.awk`¹).

```
perl -lae 'print unless $F[0] =~ /^UUID=/ && $F[1] ne "/boot"' /etc/fstab
```

(`perl` has `-i` for in place editing).

The equivalent could be done with `sed` with:

```
sed '/^[[:space:]]*[^[:space:]]\{1,\}[[:space:]]\{1,\}/boot\([[:space:]].*\)\{0,1\}$/b
     /^[[:space:]]*UUID=/d' /etc/fstab
```

Some `sed`s can do in-place editing with either `-i` (most) or `-i ''` (FreeBSD and derivatives including macos).

---

<sup>¹ **do not use `-i inplace`** as `gawk` tries to load the `inplace` extension (as `inplace` or `inplace.awk`) from the current working directory first, where someone could have planted malware. The path of the `inplace` extension supplied with `gawk` may vary with the system, see the output of `gawk 'BEGIN{print ENVIRON["AWKPATH"]}'`</sup>

Comment: Or `awk '/^UUID=/ && $2 != "/boot"{next} 1' /etc/fstab` or `awk '!/^UUID=/ || $2 == "/boot"` to avoid the double negative in `! (... $2 != "/boot")`

Comment: BTW , we try the syntax - perl -lae 'print unless $F[0] =~ /^UUID=/ && $F[1] ne "/boot"' /etc/fstab , but its not remove dthe UUID , we have RHEL 7.9 version

Comment: It does remove the lines that start with `UUID=` except for the one for `/boot` in the sample in your question though. Does it not for you?

Comment: in my case the UUID are really start in the begining of the line but they still exist so perl not removed them

Comment: I also take my example and its not works with the perl syntax., so maybe you not used RHEL 7.X version, maybes something with ENV is diff

Comment: @yael, that syntax would have worked even in perl 3 in the 80s. Maybe you expected that to edit the file in-place (for which you'd need to add the `-i` option as indicated)?

Answer (score 4):

There are many possibilities. Keeping it simple you can use

```
'/^UUID/{
   /\/boot/b
   d
}'
```

which uses `{}` to enclose more commands to do when the pattern is matched. If boot is matched, `b` branches to the end of the commands, else the `d` is done. Alternatively,

```
'/^UUID/{
   /\/boot/!d
}'
```

If boot is *not* matched, do the delete.
These patterns should be enhanced with matches for whitespace, but you may not care to if you understand what you are expecting in the file.

The one-line versions may not work with some version of `sed`:

```
'/^UUID/{/\/boot/b;d;}'
```

and

```
'/^UUID/{/\/boot/!d;}'
```

Comment: can you update your answer with one liners sed line ?

Comment: I added the one-liners.

Comment: *The one-line versions may not work with older version of sed*. It's not about old vs new, it's about which sed implementation. Standardly, you need to separate the `d` from the `}` with either newline or `;`

Comment: Thanks, I added a semi-colon for more portability, though this [POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html) doc says `b` cannot be followed by `;`.

Answer (score 2):

##### With [perl](/questions/tagged/perl):

```
perl -i -pe 's@^UUID\S+\s++(?!/boot).*\n@@' /etc/fstab
```

The `-i` like in `sed`, replace *in line*

##### The regular expression matches as follows:

| Node | Explanation |
| --- | --- |
| `^` | the beginning of the string |
| `UUID` | 'UUID' |
| `\S+` | non-whitespace (all but \n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1 or more times (matching the most amount possible)) |
| `\s++` | whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") Match 1 or more times and give nothing back |
| `(?!` | [look ahead](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=518444) to see if there is not: |
| `/boot` | '/boot' |
| `)` | end of look-ahead |
| `.*` | any character except \n (0 or more times (matching the most amount possible)) |
| `\n` | '\n' (newline) |

Answer (score 2):

I'd do this in awk, myself, since we can take advantage of the default action when something evaluates to true which is to print the line. So all we need is to test that either this line matches `boot` or doesn't match `UUID`:

```
$ awk '/boot/ || !/UUID/' file 
/dev/mapper/VG100-lv_root /                       xfs     defaults        0 0
UUID=735cb76a-51b5-4e06-b6fb-3b9577e38dc5 /boot                   xfs     defaults        0 0
/dev/mapper/VG100-lv_var /var                    xfs     defaults        0 0
```

You can also remove the blank lines:

```
$ awk '/./ && (/boot/ || !/UUID/)' file 
/dev/mapper/VG100-lv_root /                       xfs     defaults        0 0
UUID=735cb76a-51b5-4e06-b6fb-3b9577e38dc5 /boot                   xfs     defaults        0 0
/dev/mapper/VG100-lv_var /var                    xfs     defaults        0 0
```

And you can make it a bit safer by ensuring that `/boot` is matched, and as a single "word", and that `UUID` is at the beginning of the line and followed by `=`:

```
awk '/./ && (/\/boot\>/ || !/^UUID=/)' file
```

And, with GNU awk, you can use `-i inplace` to edit the original file, just like `sed`:

```
gawk -i inplace '/./ && (/boot/ || !/UUID/)' file
```

If you absolutely must use `sed`, here's yet another approach:

```
$ sed -n '/\/boot/p; /UUID/!p' file
/dev/mapper/VG100-lv_root /                       xfs     defaults        0 0
UUID=735cb76a-51b5-4e06-b6fb-3b9577e38dc5 /boot                   xfs     defaults        0 0
/dev/mapper/VG100-lv_var /var                    xfs     defaults        0 0
```

The `-n` turns off line printing, and then we print (`p`) if the line matches `/boot` or if it doesn't match `UUID` (the `!p` at the end of `/UUID/!p` means "print if it does NOT match").

Finally, here's another perl approach:

```
$ perl -ne 'print if /\/boot/ || !/UUID/ ' file
/dev/mapper/VG100-lv_root /                       xfs     defaults        0 0
UUID=735cb76a-51b5-4e06-b6fb-3b9577e38dc5 /boot                   xfs     defaults        0 0
/dev/mapper/VG100-lv_var /var                    xfs     defaults        0 0
```

Answer (score 2):

I can not stress this enough: **You do not want to do this with a sed script**.

Use something like Ansible instead.

Just a quick perusal of the [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/posix/mount_module.html) for its `mount` module suggests you could automate it for your entire 2500+ cluster of systems with something along the following lines:

```yaml
name: Remove kafka1 mount
  ansible.posix.mount:
    backup: true
    path: '/var/kafka/{{ item }}'
    state: absent
  loop:
    - 'mp1'
    - 'mp2'
    - 'mp3'
```

This will

1. Obviate the need for meticulously nitpicked pattern matching which may or may not work for all cases;
2. Allow you to run the script on all systems with just one call, avoiding typos caused by repetitive work
3. Generate a backup of your fstab entry you'll be able to recover from should it turn out you missed something after all
4. Permit you to **test** things before you run the script and potentially render 2000+ systems unusable.